# Populating a UIViewPicker with JSON Array data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im new to swift.

I am querying a web service to get relevant data back.

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "description" : "9 Sea View Road"
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "description" : "10 Random Street"
  }
]
```

How do i sift through this returned data and then populate a UIPickerView?

Ive got the data with this:

```
let venues = JSON(data:tabletData)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//First use to viewdidload 
if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let venues = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return venues.count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return venues[row].valueForKey("description")as? String
}
```

I hope this work.